# What is the make: *** [test] Error 10 signify?

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I run a program using Makefile and it is giving me a strange error, although successfully executed. `make: *** [test] Error 10`

Here is my Makefile code

```
30 
31 test:
32         @ echo
33         @ echo "Testing Electric Fence."
34         @ echo "After the last test, it should print that the test has PASSED."
35         ./eftest
36         ./tstheap 3072
37         @ echo
38         @ echo "Starting test for time-interval-measurement."
39        export EF_ERRTRACK_START=3; export EF_ERRTRACK_END=5; ./time-interval-measurement-test
40         @ echo
41         @ echo "Electric Fence confidence test PASSED." 
42         @ echo
```

On execution:

```
Time interval measurement test: PASSED
make: *** [test] Error 10
-bash-3.2# make test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To workaround that (in case you cannot modify the (return/exit) behaviour of your binaries) use

```
./exec || /bin/true
```

.

Comment: In makefile? you mean `export EF_ERRTRACK_START=3; export EF_ERRTRACK_END=5; ./time-interval-measurement-test || /bin/true`

Comment: In case ./exec returns something not equal to 0 it calls /bin/true which returns 0. 0 means true in a unix-shell.

Comment: :Upvote for you :) But please tell me what does that command do.

Answer (score 1):

> [foo] Error NN’
>
> These errors are not really make errors at all. They mean that a program that make invoked as part of a recipe returned a non-0 error code (‘Error NN’), which make interprets as failure, or it exited in some other abnormal fashion (with a signal of some type). See [Errors In Recipes.](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Errors.html#Errors)
>
> If no ** * is attached to the message, then the subprocess failed but the rule in the makefile was prefixed with the - special character, so make ignored the error.

http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Error-Messages.html

So one of your commands is returning a non-zero error code.

Comment: How to suppress that? I feel i am only executing the target `./time-interval-measurement-test `

Answer (score 0):

One of your command exits with error. Not `echo`, the other ones. Check them.

Comment: In makefile? What does err no 10 signify?